# Trying to send a SignalR Group message fails with an exception

Tags: signalr

I was following the SignalR documentation on Github to message a group. I join just fine with:

```
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");
```

But then when I try and send a message to all the users in that group with:

```
Clients.Group("foo").syncShortList(id);
```

I get an exception. I know there's nothing wrong with 'id'. The code will never continue after this line, so I set the debugger to catch all thrown exceptions, and found out that the second line throws the exception:

```
'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.GroupProxy' does not contain a definition for 'syncShortList'
```

I know for sure that I'm listening for the event in javascript:

```
funnelHub.client.syncShortList = function (id) {
    console.log("syncing");
    console.log(id);
}
```

The event is never getting fired. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong with this? I'm running SignalR 1.0.1

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr the error is a First Chance Runtime Binder exception that happens on the first invoke on the group dynamic object.  In the end it's harmless.